# call a stored procedure and stored function in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have created a store procedure in mysql

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`sqladmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_GetContainerPath`(IN P_ContainerId INT,
                                    OUT P_ContainerPath VARCHAR (255))
 Begin
   SELECT sf_GetContainerPath(P_ContainerId)
 INTO P_ContainerPath; END
```

this procedure gives all the path from my containerPath. Now i am creatting a application in vb.net, while i press the button, then i can get all that  containerPath through this procedure.

```
Friend Function getContainerpath(ByVal containerId As Integer) As DataSet
    Try
        Dim dbh As New DatabaseHandler
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim inParams As New Hashtable
        Dim outParams As New Hashtable

        inParams.Add("P_ContainerId", containerId)
        outParams.add("P_ContainerPath", Nothing)
        ds = dbh.callPro2("sp_GetContainerPath", inParams, outParams)


        Return ds

    Catch ex As Exception
        logException("getContainerpath", ex.Message)
        Throw
    End Try
End Function
Private Sub GetContainerButton_Click(ByVal containerid, sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GetContainerButton.Click         end sub

   Friend Sub callProc2(ByVal procName As String, ByVal inParams As Hashtable, ByRef outParams As Hashtable, _
                     Optional ByRef inoutParams As Hashtable = Nothing)
    logQuery("callProc2", procName, inParams, inoutParams)
    Dim elapsedTicks As Long
    Dim elapsedSpan As New TimeSpan(elapsedTicks)
    elapsedTicks = Date.Now.Ticks
    Try
        If Not inParams.Contains("P_UserId") Then
            inParams.Add("P_UserId", ConfigurationHandler.UserId)
        End If
        If Not inParams.Contains("P_MachineId") Then
            inParams.Add("P_MachineId", ConfigurationHandler.machineId)
        End If
        If Not inParams.Contains("P_ApplicationId") Then
            inParams.Add("P_ApplicationId", ConfigurationHandler.applicationId)
        End If

        'Do the actual query
        '
        Select Case UCase(_dbType)
            Case "MYSQL"
                callSQLProc(procName, inParams, outParams, inoutParams)
            Case "XML"
                _xmlDatabase.callXMLProc(procName, inParams, outParams, inoutParams)
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception("INVALID_DATABASE_TYPE")
        End Select

    Catch ex As Exception                                   'generic .net error
        logException("callProc2", ex.Message)
        Throw
    Finally
        logResult("callProc2", procName, outParams, inoutParams)
        elapsedSpan = New TimeSpan(Date.Now.Ticks - elapsedTicks)
        logVerbose("DatabaseHandler:callProc2[" & procName & "]-Elapsed: " & elapsedSpan.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

this is piece of vb code i wrote it to get the path from stored procedure. but it doesn't run. anyone help? cheers

Comment: Without the code of dbh.callProcReturn is not possible to say what's going wrong. Did you get any exception logged by your try/catch handler?

Comment: hi steve. i wrote my ds = dbh.callProcReturn("sp_GetContainerPath", inParams, outParams). i did not get exception. idk why. i just cannot get the path in my list

Comment: Hi steve, i update my question. Free to have a look? cheers

Comment: Now you are shifting the problem to another method that we cannot see the code. callSqlProc. I think that to resolve your troubles we should see the point where your inParams, outParams hashtables are passed as real MySqlParameters to a MySqlCommand and the native ADO.NET ExecuteNonQuery/ExecuteReader method are called.

Comment: Of course I assume that if you execute your Stored Procedure in MySqlWorkbench you get the expected results.

Comment: i can get my results in workbench, but can you show me how to call the getContainerPath in my GetContainerButton_Click? somethinglike getcontainerPath()?

Comment: I think we have the same problem running the stored procedure is working fine when implemented on vb.net but with stored function ? it just gonna load until the timeout expired.